# Gradle Upgrade issue: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Version must not be null o empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

we are facing issue while upgrading gradle 5.6 to gradle 7.2.

we have simple spring boot project(sub1) with one internal spring library project(sub 2). while sub2 is gradle spring lib which depends on sub1. Both projects are using same gradle and spring boot version.

Also we are trying to upgrade spring cloud to latest version which requires gradle upgrade and spring boot upgade. current version is shown below

1. gradle - 7.2
2. spring - 2.5.2
3. swagger - 2.9.2

Getting below error while I try hitting swagger url.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Version must not be null o empty`

Spring boot banner is blank and not showing version. we are suspecting this could be the issue.

Swagger home page shows below error:

`Failed to load API definition`

**Gradle file**:

```
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.8"
    id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "2.2.2"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: "jacoco"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}

configurations {
  implementation.canBeResolved = true
}

jar {
    archiveVersion = "${project.findProperty('APP_VERSION') ?: 'MANUAL_BUILD'}"
    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from {
        (configurations.runtimeClasspath-configuration.implementation).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.3.8')
    implementation('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.33')
    implementation('org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.5')
 }
```

Please help us understand this issue.

Answer (score 0):

there are some new features added as well as some features from gradle5X removed so, please go through the documentation once again and try to add the below dependencies that may help you in your API.

```
dependencies {
// Ensure you use the Groovy 3.x variant
testImplementation('org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-groovy-3.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy'
}
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api')
```

}

```
// Spock 2 is based on JUnit Platform and needs to be enabled explicitly.
tasks.withType(Test).configureEach {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

also, go through this once to get more in detailed https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html